# Trying to Mask Text in Ai. It is not going well

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, mask

When I follow the instructions in the Adobe tutorial the mask is created but the color is totally off. I am using a gold texture and the screenshot below is what I end up with.

here's what it looks like before the mask (box and text are grouped)

[image]

then here's what it looks like when I use the mask (first mage shows transparency palette and placed image outline)

[image]

it doesn't seem to matter if the text is white or black, if the texture is clipped or unclipped, masked or inverted. I am pulling my hair out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not seen the tutorial, but watched your image.

Seemingly you have used the texture pattern to make your textbox partially transparent. You should have done the opposite. If you make the opacity mask, the topmost shape in the arrange list is the mask.

So, have a piece of the texture pattern at the same place as your textbox. Bring the textbox to the front, select both and make the opacity mask.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!  However my client asked for a box around the text and when I add a rectangle, make the fill transparent and the line a 3pt white line then try the same method, I end up with a filled rectangle and no outline. Do I need to draw lines to make this work?

Comment: @mdobrien74 Check, have you inverted the mask.! Normally white means visible, black means = not visible. If your opacity mask contains tansparent areas, that you also want to cause transparency,  you should select the option Clip = ON .